# Sublime Text 2 overrides Winamp Keyboard Hotkeys

Tags: windows-8, sublime-text-2, winamp

This is the layout of my keyboard (Multimedia-Keys)

```
Play|Pause  ,  Mute  , Vol-  ...
```

I however change songs very very often (next in playlist, prev in playlist), for which I do not have multimedia keys available.

I use `Winamp`, and use global Hotkeys to override the default action to what I want and it works perfectly.

```
Play|Pause  ,  Prev  , Next ...
```

The only problem is, when I use `Sublime-Text-2`, where the keys use the default action, instead of the Winamp Overrides.

I know of User Key-Bindings in `Sublime-Text-2`, however, do not know the key : value for this combination.

```
{ "keys": ["?"], "command": "?" }
// { "keys": ["multimedia-play-key"], "command": "do nothing" }
```

Is there a way in Sublime Text to ignore all mutimedia keys ?

I'm using `Windows8`.

Thanks.